# Как создаются игры?

Tags: javascript, java, c#, c++, c

Как всё таки создаются большие игры? Я представлял что на языке программирования с или с++ и т.д., но наткнулся на видео как делают какую то "игру" на движке unreal engine 4, и так даже близко не было видно ни какого кода.Как всё таки создаются игры или что то отдельно пишется на яп, и накладываются текстуры на движках или как то по другому ни как не могу понять.

Comment: На C++ обычно создаются движки. На движках создаются игры. Но обычно для создания хороших игр все равно пишут много кода.

Comment: Игры очень разные и создаются по-разному. Какого-то одного стандартного способа нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кто то покупает движок или использует бесплатный - `Unreal Engine`, `Unity`. В первом код можно не писать - поскольку есть графическое представление логики в виде Blueprint'оф. В Unity код пишется на `C#`, и все они как правило они предоставляют удобный редактор, для организации работы с ресурсами и прочей рутиной. Есть даже дико специфические движки - представляющие из себя относительно простой редактор, где можно создать несложные игры: `GameMaker`, `RPG Maker` и т.д. Кто-то пишет свой движок. И уже сверху наворачивает игру, в рукопашку, или написав тоже какой-то редактор в помощь. В любом случае ответ на вопрос слишком обширный, чтобы можно было на него ответить здесь. Посмотрите обучающие видео по `Unity`, вполне доступный способ сделать игру даже не шибко умея программировать.

А написать свой движок - это достаточно дорогая затея, и требует больших знаний в работе с графическими апи (DirectX, OpenGL), программировании, и даже математики (а как вы хотели, физика может быть очень сложной штукой).

Answer (score 1):

В UDK(это сокращенно Unreal Development Kit) есть система так называемых Blueprints). Если короче, то этот движок сложноват для начинания. Советую начать с Construct2, потом попробовать свои силы в Unity. По всем этим движкам в сети много информации, по Unity немало книг на русском.

Answer (score 0):

Движки — это специальные программы, которые облегчают разработку игр. Они создаются большими студиями (unreal engine разрабатывается Epic Games, Unity — Unity Technologies) для своих проектов или продажи.

Если говорить про unreal engine, то последней, актуальной версией пользуется Epic Games, а устаревшие версии выкладывает в свободный доступ.

> наткнулся на видео как делают какую то "игру" на движке unreal engine
>   4, и так даже близко не было видно никакого кода.

Во многие движки разработчики встраивают не только физику игры, чтобы не пришлось при разработке нового проекта писать код "с нуля", но и предусматривают систему визуального программирования, где можно соединяя квадратики линиями генерировать код.

Это все сделано для того, чтобы разработчик не забивая голову сложными расчетами, мог быстро (относительно, конечно) выполнить свою часть работы.

Писать свой движок дорого, это требует времени и хорошей базы знаний, поэтому многие маленькие студии или отдельные инди-разработчики пользуются движками других студий.

Answer (score 0):

Разрабатывать игру на движках типа Unreal Engine или Uniti в одиночку - это миф недостижимым! Тут мало знать функционал движка и уметь программировать, ещё нужно уметь моделировать хотя бы простые вещи, а для сложных надо ещё уметь навестить на них анимацию. Да и тема материалов тут идёт рядом, не будет же мир в игре из простого цвета.